# Determining what type of Project to create to build a mono-compatible class library in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, mono, cross-platform, monogame

I'm building a multi platform application, leveraging MonoGame, but I'm very new to Mono development. I have a few questions as a result.

1. Is it reasonable to do all of my development in Visual Studio 2012 for now and then when I'm ready to target non-Microsoft environments move to MonoDevelop?
2. What kind of configuration do I need to do in order to develop a class library that can be utilized on any target system that runs Mono?
3. Is it ill advised to allow Windows environments to run the application as a .NET application and let the other deployments run on Mono or is there a compelling reason to choose a flat Mono configuration (or indeed are there benefits to running as a .NET application?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just completed my first MonoGame game targeting Android so I'm not claiming to be the expert but I will tell you what I know.

1) I used MonoDevelop for almost all of the development of my game. However, I did load it up in Visual Studio a couple of times and had no issues compiling and running it.

2) You basically have 2 options to develop shared libraries.

The first is Portable Class Libraries that allow you to reference the same DLL from each project. They are specifically designed for this purpose, but are limited to a subset of functionality based on the frameworks your targeting.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/gg597391.aspx

The second option is file linking. You can include the same code file into multiple projects by creating a link to the file in all but one of the projects. This approach is a bit more flexible but can be a bit of a maintenance issue.

3) In theory it will work, but there's no guarantee that Mono's implementation is going to be the same as Microsoft's. So at the very least you would have to test it fairly thoroughly on each if you have a good reason to do so. I don't really see any advantages though.